# Api de laravel funciona en local, pero no en servidor

Tags: laravel, api

Estoy trabajando en una aplicacion movil, decidimos usar laravel para el backend.
Cuando consumo la api localmente no tengo problema, el problema ocurre una vez subimos el proyecto al servidor, en postman me arroja un 404.

**Ruta en api**

`Route::post('/autentificacion', [AutentificacionController::class, 'autentificacion'])->name('autentificacion');`

**Controlador**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use App\Models\Empleados;

class AutentificacionController extends BaseController
{
  use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;



  public function autentificacion(Request $request){

    $usuario = Empleados::where('no_empleado',$request->no_empleado)
    ->where('imss',$request->imss)
    ->first();

    if($usuario == null){
        return response()->json(['info_user' => $usuario, 'acceso' => FALSE], 200);
    }else{
        return response()->json(['info_user' => $usuario, 'acceso' => TRUE], 200);
    }
  }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya probe cambiando en htacces, el punto env, la ruta y no encuentro la soluciòn, alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema puede ser que en el archivo `.htaccess` o en alguna regla del servidor, la ruta es `/api` por default.

Deberias llamar al endpoint asi: `http://18.216.59.252/autentificacion`